# How to get the list of dates in a given range with recursion

Tags: android, kotlin, recursion, recurrence

I want to create a function that returns a list of dates in the given range, with recursion. I will provide the starting date, the ending date, and the type of recursion. I am not sure how to start. Any suggestions would be helpful. Is there any library for this, or do I have to do it on my own?

```
data class Date(
    val day: Int,
    val month: Int,
    val year: Int
)

enum class Recursion {
    NEVER,
    EVERY_DAY,
    EVERY_WORK_DAY,
    EVERY_WEEK,
    EVERY_MONTH,
    ANNUAL
}

fun createListOfEvents(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, recursion: Recursion): List<Date>{
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "with recursion"? What's this parameter is for - `recursion: Recursion`? Do you mean step for dates?

Comment: Yes, thats what I ment

Comment: You should remove the `recursion` tag. "Recursion" has a very specific meaning in programming, but you are using the other meaning of the word. I can't remove it because someone else started an edit of your post that has to be approved by one more person.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you need recursion for this, exactly? Have you tried writing any code to fill in the function stub here? Where are you stuck? Thanks for the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) if targeting SDK < 26.

Then you can use the LocalDate class for this. Your Date class is kind of redundant, but you could convert inside the function to LocalDate if you want to keep it.

```
fun createListOfEvents(startDate: LocalDate, endDate: LocalDate, recursion: Recursion): List<LocalDate> {
    val step = when (recursion) {
        Recursion.NEVER -> return emptyList()
        Recursion.EVERY_DAY, Recursion.EVERY_WORK_DAY -> Period.ofDays(1)
        Recursion.EVERY_WEEK -> Period.ofWeeks(1)
        Recursion.EVERY_MONTH -> Period.ofMonths(1)
        Recursion.ANNUAL -> Period.ofYears(1)
    }
    var date = startDate
    val list = mutableListOf<LocalDate>()
    while (date <= endDate) {
        list.add(date)
        date += step
    }
    if (recursion == Recursion.EVERY_WORK_DAY) {
        val weekend = listOf(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
        list.removeAll { it.dayOfWeek in weekend }
    }
    return list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically this is an example of how you can do this:

```
data class Recursion(val field : TemporalUnit, val step: Long)

    val step1Day = Recursion(field = ChronoUnit.DAYS, step = 1)

    fun createListOfEvents(startDate: LocalDate, endDate: LocalDate, recursion: Recursion): List<LocalDate>{
        var currentDate = startDate
        val listOfDates = mutableListOf<LocalDate>()
        while (currentDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
            listOfDates.add(currentDate)
            currentDate = startDate.plus(recursion.step, recursion.field)
        }
        return listOfDates
    }
```

This method returns list of dates from startDate until endDate with the step of Recursion.
As you can see I've used `java.time.*` classes for this, but eventually you can convert them into your own Date and Recursion and back.
Here TemporalUnit can be `DAYS, WEEKS, MONTHS, YEARS` (and other).
It covers most of your needs, working days you will have to manage manually.
Hope this makes sense )